# Maximum Upload size

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

The Maximum Upload size is '50MB' for a web-application, will it be the same for the site-collections underneath of that web-application?

Comment: turn versioning off. We have a library with 50MB docs and it grows too rapidly with versioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limit is for everything under the webapp.

If you plan on increasing it significantly, you may also need to increase some other settings in IIS and/or SharePoint to make sure connections don't timeout.

In IIS: Connection Timeout limit
In SharePoint: [large file chunk size](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262061.aspx)

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/06/27/file-name-length-size-and-invalid-character-restrictions-and-recommendations.aspx) for some good insights on this. It is old, but not outdated I think.